# firefox giving error while using install button on gnome-look.org

Tags: 17.04, mozilla

i am using ubuntu 17.04 which gnome shell , while installing files from the gnome-look.org  gives error earlier it used to work with ubuntu 16.04 
[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you still have the software to open the OCS link? I'm not near a Ubuntu machine currently but I believe if you hit that question mark it will tell you what software/firefox extension to install in order to enable that "install" button on the website. When you click that link it opens a page with an "ocs://" extension, which is why you got that error. You will need the software that recognizes it.

Comment: then how i can install whatever this software is ..i am not so good with ubuntu  and cannot use windows

Answer (score 0):

Here's the information from the (?) Icon I had previously mentioned in my comment.

**Download the .deb file for the "open Desktop" application**
This is a direct link
[here.](https://dl.opendesktop.org/api/files/download/id/1492685474/opendesktop-app_0.1.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb)
 The actual site is here:
[Linux-apps](https://www.linux-apps.com/p/1175480/)

Then you click the "files" tab and download the .deb for your distribution. Once you open the .deb file your package manager (ubuntu software center) should open and allow you to install it.

**If you would rather use ocs-url app**

You can get it from [here.](https://www.linux-apps.com/p/1136805/)
A direct-link for the deb file is [here.](https://dl.opendesktop.org/api/files/download/id/1488740853/ocs-url_3.0.0-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb)
The Installation instructions also include a video of how to install ocs-url. That link is [here](https://youtu.be/R2qgkPrHutE)

> If you use Firefox, a program selection window open the first time you click on an install button. Choose "ocs-url" as custom url handler and tick "remember the file association".

So following instructions from the gnome-look.org help button next to the install button, follow the steps I just outlined to install the URL handler, once that is installed you can now use the "install" button on the gnome-look.org site.

I hope that helps.